# How i can use 'list' object on other attributes on xml.etree.ElementTree parse

Tags: python, xml

Please tell me how to be? I want to receive the text and tags of all the children "alarmTime". However, I get an error. How to assign the attribute 'list'? Or tell me how to avoid the error.

My code is:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


tree = ET.parse('sample.xml')

root = tree.getroot()

for elem in root.iter(tag ='alarmTime'):
    data = elem.getchildren()

    print(data.text)
```

Error is:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: the error is verbose and intuitive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're having is that `getchildren()` returns a list of the child elements, not a single element. So this list doesn't have the `.text` attribute. To access this, you now need to loop over this list (of child elements) and retrieve the `text` for each of them.

You can do this really easily with the `ElementTree` package, as it lets you treat the element like a list containing its child elements. So you don't need to use `.getchildren` to make a list of child elements - `elem` itself is already one. (Since this feature was introduced, `.getchildren` is deprecated, and you're encouraged to use the list-like features instead).

So your code should look something like this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


tree = ET.parse('sample.xml')

root = tree.getroot()

# find each alarmTime element
for elem in root.iter(tag ='alarmTime'):
    # loop over its child elements
    for child_elem in elem:
        # print the tag and text
        print(child_elem.tag)
        print(child_elem.text)
```

Obviously, you might want to store this information, rather than just printing it. If you're expecting to find multiple copies of the `alarmTime` element, each with child elements whose `tag` and `text` you want to retrieve, I'd use a list of lists, with each child element stored as a tuple of its `tag` and `text`. I also normally use the term *subelement* rather than *child element*:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


tree = ET.parse('sample.xml')

root = tree.getroot()

# main list for alarmTime data
alarmTime_list = []
for elem in root.iter(tag ='alarmTime'):
    # create a list for data from this alarmTime element
    data = []
    # loop over subelements
    for subelem in elem:
        # add the subelement tag and text as a tuple
        data.append((subelem.tag, subelem.text))
    # add the set of data for this alarmTime element to the main list
    alarmTime_list.append(data)
```

These references might be helpful for you:

- I found this quite helpful as an introduction when I was learning to use ElementTree: http://effbot.org/zone/element.htm
- This is more detailed, and also covers `iter()` and `iterparse()`:
  https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/03/15/processing-xml-in-python-with-elementtree
- The official docs are quite good too:
  https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html